# Set Travis to test every commit from pull request

Tags: git, travis-ci

Is it possible to configure Travis CI in a way that when a pull request arrives (with multiple commits), it builds every commit and passes the unit tests in every commit of the PR?

Default is that only run against the branch head.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: To check for no broken commits. Having no broken commits preserves git bisectability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Travis features a flag for doing this, a one-line Bash script does this, see

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9183#issuecomment-473027249

Basically:

```sh
for C in {32..0}; do git push origin testbranch~${C}:testbranch; sleep 360; done
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible. If you want to test every single commit push commits one by one.

Comment: It has to be an alternative... such as calling travis api for every commit in the pull request.

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests/ Travis CI builds a pull request when it is first opened, and whenever commits are added to the pull request.